# Move specified lines down with C-(N) C-n

Tags: motion

I could move next 4 lines with `C-u C-n`,
Additionally, try to move next 6 lines with `C-6 C-n`, but it did only one line down in effect.

What's wrong with my usage?

Comment: Do you see that when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? I don't. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit (and perhaps delete the question in that case). Also, try `M-6` instead of `C-6`. And maybe see what `C-h k C-6` tells you.

Comment: Are you running Emacs in a terminal?  If so, it likely doesn't send `C-<N>` sequences to Emacs at all.  `M-<N>` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks -- I didn't know that `C-[digit]` ran **digit-argument**.  I always believed the numeric parameter comes after the `C-u`, thus the command would be `C-u 6 C-n`.  For myself, I prefer `Meta-6 C-n`.  The suggestions by @Drew are good ones: see what `C-h k C-6` pulls up, then search through your .emacs.el file.